# Leaflet markercluster plugin also showing unclustered points

Tags: leaflet, clustering

The following code displays clusters correctly. However, it also displays all the points as well as the clusters, which I don't want. What have I done wrong? Apologies that I cannot simplify the example very much - it's generated code, not handwritten.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/qgis2web.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/label.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
        <script src="js/leaflet-hash.js"></script>
        <script src="js/label.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">

    </div>

        <script src="data/json_point.js"></script>
        <script>
        var map = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:true, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
        }).fitBounds([[47.7952180701,1.50842980734],[52.7080065978,20.0920555596]]);
        var hash = new L.Hash(map);
        var additional_attrib = '<a href="https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web" target ="_blank">qgis2web</a>';
        var feature_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
        var bounds_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
        var raster_group = new L.LayerGroup([]);
        var layerOrder = new Array();
        function stackLayers() {
            for (index = 0; index < layerOrder.length; index++) {
                map.removeLayer(layerOrder[index]);
                map.addLayer(layerOrder[index]);
            }
        }
        function restackLayers() {
            for (index = 0; index < layerOrder.length; index++) {
                layerOrder[index].bringToFront();
            }
        }
        map.on('overlayadd', restackLayers);
        layerControl = L.control.layers({},{},{collapsed:false});
        function pop_point(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table><tr><th scope="row">osm_id</th><td>' + (feature.properties['osm_id'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['osm_id'])) : '') + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">name</th><td>' + (feature.properties['name'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['name'])) : '') + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">type</th><td>' + (feature.properties['type'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['type'])) : '') + '</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">population</th><td>' + (feature.properties['population'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['population'])) : '') + '</td></tr></table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        }

        function doStylepoint() {
            return {
                radius: 2.0,
                fillColor: '#843768',
                color: '#000000',
                weight: 0.0,
                opacity: 1.0,
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 1.0
            }
        }
        function doPointToLayerpoint(feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, doStylepoint())
        }
        var json_pointJSON = new L.geoJson(json_point, {
            onEachFeature: pop_point, 
            pointToLayer: doPointToLayerpoint
            });
        layerOrder[layerOrder.length] = json_pointJSON;

        var cluster_grouppointJSON = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover: false});
        cluster_grouppointJSON.addLayer(json_pointJSON);

        bounds_group.addLayer(json_pointJSON);
        cluster_grouppointJSON.addTo(map);
        raster_group.addTo(map);
        //feature_group.addTo(map);
        stackLayers();
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very last instruction `stackLayers()` adds all layers in `layerOrder` array to the map.

Since `json_pointJSON` is added into `layerOrder` instead of the `cluster_grouppointJSON` it is embedded in, both Layer Groups appear on the map at initialization. If you zoom in until clustering stops, and zoom back out, the circle markers disappear as expected.

If your code generation tool can register `cluster_grouppointJSON` into `layerOrder` instead of `json_pointJSON`, it would solve your issue.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QOIwq5G5qSQjI8iQkYTb?p=preview

Note: strangely, I do not see any script include of `leaflet.js` in your page, maybe you have stripped it out by mistake?

Comment: Ah, of course. Let me test that and confirm - it sounds like you are definitely right. stackLayers() is present to try to preserve the z-index of the layers in the map. I'll see if I can get it to add the cluster group to add to layerOrder instead of the layer itself, as you suggest.

Comment: Many thanks - 100% correct, and extremely prompt and helpful. In the code above, adding cluster_grouppointJSON to layerOrder instead of pointJSON solves the issue.